# Farthest points in asymmetric 2D closed curve

Tags: symmetry

Is there a mathematically proper name for the two points that are located farther away from each other in a 2D asymmetric closed curve? See the image below to get an idea of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: I am not familiar with an explicit name. Have you worked out the geometrical condition for this to happen? (It involves the normal lines.) Perhaps you could use that to invent a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of points with this property ($d(a,b)=\operatorname{diam}C$) is called a [diametral pair](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=%22diametral+pair%22).

Every compact set has at least one diametral pair. It is not unique in general (e.g., for a circle).

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for the answer!